# Edit multiple images in Laravel

Tags: laravel, file-upload

When updating multiple images how can I know **which** image user selected to edit it in database and unlink the old one then upload the new one ?

```
@foreach ($part->images as $key=>$image)
      <input type="file" name="part_img[]"  value="{{ $image->id }}" />
@endforeach
```

Comment: Do you have multiple images has multiple rows or single rows?

Comment: Multiple row in pivot table
(img_id,part_id)

Comment: Please do not share images for code blocks, instead use the code snippet

Comment: Sorry this is my first post

Comment: @SezoHessen, You have already do this. You pass image id. So check image_id and image in db

Comment: @A.ANoman this is input file when i dd($request->file('part_img')) it return only the information of this file only

Answer (score 0):

You pass a `hidden` input field to get `image_id` in `foreach` loop

```
<input type="text" name="image_id[]"  value="{{ $image->id }}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

image id should be the key of part_img[]

```
<input type="file" name="part_img[{{ $image->id }}]"  />
```

Then in controller

```
if($request->file('part_img')){
  $images  = $request->file('part_img');
  foreach($images as $key=>$image){
          //Here update the image with $key equal to image id
   }
}
```